# dynamic selection in SQL aggregate function

Tags: sql

Imagine I have a column with row data A, B, and C.  When aggregating the column, I want B to show up if any row contains B, else C, else A.

Is this possible?  I'm using vertica but would be curious to hear solutions for other data stores.

```
+------+-------+
| Col1 | Col 2 |
+------+-------+
| A    |   X   |
| B    |   X   |
| C    |   X   |
+------+-------+

SELECT ???(Col1), Col2 
FROM my_two_column_table
GROUP BY Col2
```

expected result: one row - B, X

Comment: Try writing a normal query that has a column which behaves like you describe ("I want B to show up if any row contains B, else C, else A").  Then it's easy to write an aggregate.  As written, it's not a very concrete description of what you're looking for, but it sounds like you're looking for COALESCE() function.  Beyond that, you'll really need to post example data and post what you've got so far and why it isn't working.  StackOverflow isn't a code writing service yadda yadda.

Comment: Could you demonstrate us that result with some ascii table?
You have [one here](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
SELECT COALESCE( MAX(t2.value), MAX(t3.value), MAX(t4.value) )
FROM my_table t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN my_table t2 ON t2.value = 'B'
LEFT OUTER JOIN my_table t3 ON t3.value = 'C'
LEFT OUTER JOIN my_table t4 ON t4.value = 'A'
WHERE t1.value in ( 'A', 'B', 'C' )
```

The `t1` table can also be replaced by `dual` or whatever dummy table with at least one row you have.